# Adding admob ads to an app on particular activities?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android development. The app I develop has 30 activities. I'm in the process of adding admob ads to my app. Can I add ads only to 10 of 30 activities. Is it ok to add ads to only 10 activities, is it correct. If not is there any shortcuts to add ads to all activities. Shortcut in the sense programmatically adding ads to one activity and extending it to all activities.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that there is no shortcut to add it to all activities.
For putting the ad into the activities you want, put the JAVA and XML code only in the activity you want to place the ad.

Gradle is common for the whole project.

My Personal Advice - Do more code and get the concepts more well before indulging in the Ads. They are a bit complex for beginners.